# How can I access JavaScript Class and it's methods in browser Window object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a JavaScript class that I want to read and set a property called `selection` of it from another file, and I was trying to access the class/methods from the browser `window` object, but the class doesn't show up there.

I see other classes like JQuery. How can I get my class to show up in the window for global access?

Here's what I was hoping to do:

```js
class UI {
    constructor() {
        this.selection = {}; // I want to read and set this property
    }

}
```

And from another file, I was hoping to do something like this:

```js
if( window.UI.selection.name ) {
    window.UI.selection.name = 'A new name';
};
```

Is there a way to make a class globally accessible in the `window`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define a class and use its own instance variable, you can do this

```js
class UI {
    constructor() {
        this.selection = {}; // I want to read and set this property
    }
}

window.UI = new UI()
window.UI.selection.name = "foo"
console.log(window.UI.selection.name)
```

If you want to use class without `new` but with static variable, you can write the following:

```js
class UI {
    static selection = {}
}

window.UI = UI
window.UI.selection.name = "foo"
console.log(window.UI.selection.name)
```

Refrence:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Thanks for this - I just got it working by using `window.UI = new UI()`. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

## On access to UI

Since classes are a part of modern JS they, like `let` and `const` variables, do not attach themselves to the `window` object if they are created in the global scope.

You can access the UI class with its name, even in a different file, so long as you don't [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the UI variable.

```html
<script>
class UI {
    constructor() {
        this.selection = {}; // I want to read and set this property
    }

}
</script>

<script>
    console.log(UI);
</script>
```

The exception to this is if you are using modules, in which case each module will have its own scope.

In that case you *could* explicitly assign the the `window` object (`window.UI = UI`) but you shouldn't. Use `import` and `export` instead.

## On access to UI.selection.name

`selection` is an object which is created on instances of the UI class by the constructor function.

It only appears on *instances* of the class and does not appear on the class itself.

To access that you must first create an instance:

```
const ui = new UI();
ui.selection.name = "foo";
```

Comment: Ah, this is what's going wrong, as this class is a module. I'm importing methods from another file as helper functions. Since this file is only loaded on 3 products, I'm going to explicitly assign it to the Window, as this test just worked. Thanks for the explanation, I didn't realize that modules have their own scope.